# Subdomains not working on local rails env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am currently having a major problem at developing a Ruby on Rails application. I never worked with sub-domains before, but since this project it is required to do so.

---

I added every sub-domain constrain through a `scope`, but the routing doesn't work. Here is my `routes.rb`:

```
scope module: :frontend, subdomain: ':company_id' do
  resources :RESOURCE_NAME do
    scope module: 'MODULE_NAME' do
      [...] # Some simple routes
    end
  end
  [...]
end
```

So, I skipped the routes since they are not really important, they are just simple `get` and `post` things.

Now, the problem is, that every time I am calling a `*_path` method I am not redirected to the sub-domain (Since then everything worked fine with lvh.me). Every sub-domain (I have some more) are working when I am visiting them directly, but also the when I am visiting the homepage (`http://lvh.me:3000/`). The sub-domain scope `launchpad` is shown to me and not the direct root I specified in my `routes.rb`.

Now I am asking, how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to http://moo.lvh.me:3000/

Simple in your controller just do the following

```
unless request.subdomains.any?
   redirect_to subdomain: 'www'
else
   ...
   # there is no subdomain
end
```

Comment: thanks, but if i don't want to use **any** sub-domain?

Comment: then you can ignore it. or put your code in the else area.